# Facebook App-Application is misconfigured for Facebook integration

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharekit

I am developing iphone app which shares photos on social networks.For photo sharing I am using "Sharekit".I have created Facebook App and using its api key and secrete.(used correct api key and secret.).

When I try to share image with this app(even simple text),the following error comes.(even the facebook login popup doesn't appear.)

"Sorry,the application you are using misconfigured for Facebook integration.Please download the newest version of the application"

I would have uploaded snap shot but as a new user Stack overflow is not allowing to upload image..Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently this problem was faced by me too.

Since i was using their old API methods..
it is really tough to find the cause now..

Although i have not used ShareKit..i believe it is also using the older methods.

I solved the problem by using their official tutorial on [Facebook iOS integration](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

Comment: old app keys work for me too..!that is why it is really tough to say where the error can be..!

Comment: Hi Shubhank thanks..finally I had to remove sharekit and done coding separately for facebook,twitter and mail.

Comment: Anyone found a solution using sharekit??

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the version of sharekit i am using 0.2.1 is pretty outdated one. The project was moved to github and the latest version 2.0 can be found [here](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit). The home site is outdated with version 0.2.1 so follow the github link for latest update.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Socialize: http://www.GetSocialize.com, which uses the newer methods.  Full feature list at http://go.GetSocialize.com/features

Good luck!

DROdio