# iPhone:Error of misconfiguration for facebook integration occurs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sharekit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook App-Application is misconfigured for Facebook integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412416/facebook-app-application-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-integration)

I have registered my app on facebook and I use sharekit for facebook integration when I try to send msg from  my app I get the error msg as follows:

"Sorry, the application you are using is misconfigured for Facebook integration. Please download the newest version of the application."

I am not able to understand why does this msg generate?

if you have any idea then share it.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Probably happens because you are using ShareKit which is not Update.
Although Sharekit is One of the Good way to integrating the Social SDk in iphone Apps
When you are going to use ShareKit,one things You should take care is that
you will have to keep Updated Version of Sharekit.

You can see this comment on ShareKit Documentation.

"Be Sure to Stay Up to Date
To make sure you keep ShareKit up to date with the latest bug fixes, enhancements and additional services, follow ShareKit on the blog, Twitter, and/or GitHub."

I suppose You should go through below Link and just check 
are you using the Latest version Of SharekIt..?.

[You need to go through this Link for Sharekit doc](http://getsharekit.com/install/)

I Think ,It'll Really helpful to you.

Comment: I am also using facing the same problem after registering a new app on facebook. Using the latest Sharekit version 0.2.1... Anyone found anything?